# String to csv in php

Tags: php, string, csv, download

I have a string in php such as this `"Title1,Title2,Title3,row1a,row1b,row1c,row2a,row2b,row2c"` etc , basically my whole csv in one string.

I pass that string via post to my downloadcsv file which looks kinda like :

```
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=Device_List.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
$csvContent = $keys[1];
echo $csvContent;
die;
```

and I do get a csv file, however everything is on one line. The problem is I don't know how to get it to split to multiple lines for the csv. I have tried adding /n chars at the end to look like this: `"Title1,Title2,Title3\n row1a,row1b,row1c\n row2a,row2b,row2c"`

Tried with and without commas on the end, tried the \r\n, nothing seems to work. Is there a way I can write this string to csv so they go to new lines like they are supposed to? Also looked into making it into an array, but not sure if thats the route to go or how to split the string into an array containing arrays (which I believe is what you need for fputcsv).

Any ideas on how I should go about doing this?

Comment: How did you generate that string? It sounds like it should be `title1, row1a, row2a`.

Comment: So WHAT do you want in each line of your CSV

Comment: i know this may sound stupid, but have you tried with html? like <br/>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP explode
http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

PHP str_getcsv
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

use explode to split lines into array

```
$lines = explode("\n", $csv);
```

use str_getcsv to parse each line

```
foreach ($lines as &$line) {
  $cols = str_getcsv($line);
}
```